# GCM multiple line Notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notification in two line when the message text is long

I have tried this :

```
Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
            .delayWhileIdle(true).addData("message", msg).build();
```

when the text "msg" contain more char then then notification shows as
message: this is a notification msg...

how to get notification in two line instead of getting ...

Comment: pass your msg with "\n" e.g. "hello \n how are you \n what are you doing."

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = getNotificationManager();
        PendingIntent pi = getPendingIntent();
        Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

Notification notification = new Notification.BigTextStyle(builder).bigText(message).build();
```

**NOTE**

It's reports "an error": `Call requires API level 16` but i'm using on Lower APIS...

Answer (score 0):

I did it like:-

```
Message message = new Message.Builder()
                             .timeToLive(30)
                             .delayWhileIdle(true)
                             .addData("title", msgTitle)
                             .addData("text", msgText)
                             .build();
```

And in the client app side, you can extract the title and text seperately and display it in two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify from Message how many lines the notification will use when displayed. Android displays the text passed to it as is. Even if you are able to define how many lines the notification uses, that will have to be done on the Android side not the server side.

Generally you don't have control over how many lines are used in your notification. Like @Aspicas noted you can use the ContentText for a compact version of your message and then use BigTextStyle for a larger version of your message.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur. but I want to set the message contain in such a way that in client apps it appear in more then 1 line (if msg is long). So, can I do it by changing something in  my above code only.

Comment: Understood, Android notifications don't support that.